# MVC LINQ - searching/querying text with Contains in related table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq, search

I have a view that displays users. In that list, the column values come from three tables. The standard Users table from mvc applications, a Persons table which is a bunch of additional info to the Users table (Persons.UserId = Users.Id) and I have a Companies table which some persons have a reference to (Person.CompanyId = Company.Id). Some persons don't have a related company.

So I have this Linq statement that return all the persons for my view:

```
var query = from user in db.Users
            join person in db.Persons on user.Id equals person.UserID
            join company in db.Companies on person.CompanyId equals company.ID into companyResult
            from company in companyResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new PersonIndexItem { ID = person.ID, Name = user.FullName, Phone = user.PhoneNumber, Email = user.Email, Company = company == null ? "" : company.Name };
```

This works great, I have all my users and users that don't have a company relation just have nothing in the company column.

In my view, I have a Search box that matches with most of the field displayed. This is the linq statement I use:

```
var query = from user in db.Users where user.FullName.Contains(searchString) || user.Email.Contains(searchString) || user.PhoneNumber.Contains(searchString)
            join person in db.Persons on user.Id equals person.UserID
            join company in db.Companies on person.CompanyId equals company.ID into companyResult
            from company in companyResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new PersonIndexItem { ID = person.ID, Name = user.FullName, Phone = user.PhoneNumber, Email = user.Email, Company = company == null ? "" : company.Name };
```

This work great, if I type a string, it will return every records that contain that string in the user's name, phone or email.

But I would like to add the search to Companies (Name) so if I type a company name, I get all the users from that company.

I just can't make it work. Any ideas?

**EDIT** For those wondering, the data structure is the following:

```
// Users table
class User
{
  int Id;
  string FullName;
  string Email;
  string PhoneNumber;
}
// Persons table
class Person
{
  int Id;
  int UserId;     // Users table
  int CompanyId;  // Companies table
}
// Companies table
class Company
{
  int Id;
  string Name;
}
```

Comment: Are you tried like this: `from user in db.Users where user.FullName.Contains(searchString) || user.Email.Contains(searchString) || user.PhoneNumber.Contains(searchString) || user.Company.Contains(searchString) ...`? Can you explain what thing doesn't work and how?

Comment: Company is not in user. User points to a Person that points to a Company. It's two relations away :)

Comment: Hi, @FrankTKO, could you post the table structure for pointers to future suggestion?

Comment: does the company have a list of persons or just a person name

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this might not be possible with just a single query. I did two queries instead and combined them. It gets the result intended with no duplicate.

```
var query = from user in db.Users where user.FullName.Contains(searchString) || user.Email.Contains(searchString) || user.PhoneNumber.Contains(searchString)
            join person in db.Persons on user.Id equals person.UserID
            join company in db.Companies on person.CompanyId equals company.ID into companyResult
            from company in companyResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new PersonIndexItem { ID = person.ID, Name = user.FullName, Phone = user.PhoneNumber, Email = user.Email, Company = company == null ? "" : company.Name };

var query2 = from user in db.Users
             join person in db.Persons on user.Id equals person.UserID
             join company in db.Companies on person.CompanyId equals company.ID into companyResult
             from company in companyResult.DefaultIfEmpty() where company.Name.Contains(searchString)
             select new PersonIndexItem { ID = person.ID, Name = user.FullName, Phone = user.PhoneNumber, Email = user.Email, Company = company == null ? "" : company.Name };

var resultUnion = query.Union(query2);
```

If anyone has a better solution, let me know!